Understanding Data Collection & Security in Google Play Console
Google play console has made it mandatory for app developers to complete a data collection and safety declaration form. My app does not have a server, so there is no scope for data collection. 
However, I do collect analytics data using mixpanel (like time spent in certain screen, buttons clicked, etc). Also, I have an option for the user to connect to their own google drive. But having said this, I don't collect any data because the nature of my app does not require me to. I don't track the "user" in any way. 
So I replied No to the question Does your app collect or share any of the required user data types? in the form. But I recently got an email from google saying that I am in violation of the policy

We detected user data transmitted off device that you have not disclosed in your app’s Data safety form as user data collected.


You must ensure that your app’s Data safety section accurately reflects your app’s data collection, sharing, and handling practices. This includes data collected and handled through any third-party libraries or SDKs used in your app. When available, we’ve included details on SDKs that contain code similar to the code in your APK that may be sending user data off device. You can check if your app uses any of these SDKs, but note that this list of SDKs may not be exhaustive. You must review and account for all data collected and shared by your app.

How should the data collection questionaire be answered for apps such as mine which only collect analytics data and have no scope for collection of any sort of user data?

Months ago I had the same problem with my app (naive AAC on Google Play) that uses firebase-crashlytics and firebase-analytics.
I solved it by answering as follows:
Data safety section
Does the app collect or share one or more of the required types of user data? Yes
Is all user data collected by your app encrypted in transit? Yes
Which of the following account creation methods does your app support? Username, password and other authentication
Add a link that users can use to request deletion of their account and associated data :
https://naiveaac.blogspot.com/2022/11/privacy-policy-di-naive-aac.html
Do you provide a way for users to request a permanent or partial deletion of all their data without them having to delete their account? No
You must comply with Google Play's Family Policy because you've indicated that your app's target age range includes.
Do you want users to know about this commitment in the Data Security section of your Store listing? Yes
Select all types of user data collected or shared by your app : App information and performance 3/3 , Device ID or other IDs 1/1
I hope I was helpful
